# Create a batch file to update an exe file over FTP

Tags: file, batch-file, ftp, exe

I need to update an exe file on a daily basis, did create a batch file and used the 'fc' command which worked like a charm but i have two issues.

1) The newer version of the exe file would be located on an FTP site
2) The location of the older exe file would not be fixed.

The older exe file is a single executable and the problem is the user can save it anywhere, need a command so that i can locate that file compare it with the file on the FTP site and update that file if needed.

I am new to this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I basically made it such the batch file being deployed would download the updated script from FTP and run it....Although not what i was looking for but it does the trick

Answer (score 0):

well you can avoid all of this by using a briefcase then put the file that you want to update into the briefcase and then run the update manually.

but if you really want to do it with a batch file then

@echo off

cls

replace (file being updated) (updated file)

exit